# Event Triggers not working in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want create WPF controls at Runtime dynamically. In the below code, I have added `StackPanel` at XAML and crated `Button`/`TextBlock`/`Triggers` at code behind. I want to see `TextBlock` under button at `MouseEnter` action and want to hide `TextBlock` at `MouseLeave` action.
This is not working as expected. 
If add `Button`/`Textblock` code at XAML (commented now) Instead of creating them at Code behind(un commented now) then it is working fine. 
Please let me know how to fix this? Not able understand why this not working If I create the button at runtime instead of XAML code. Thanks

XAML

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel Name="stackPanel5" >
      <!--
      <Button Name="Button1" Cursor="Hand" Content="Press Me"/>
      <Border x:Name="TooltipBrd" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10,0,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Visibility="Collapsed">
         <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="Coded Test" />
      </Border>
      -->
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code

```
public void LoadData()
{
   //VisualState vs = new VisualState();
   //vs.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, YourStateName);

   Button Button1 = new Button() { Cursor = Cursors.Hand, Content = "Press Me!" };
   stackPanel5.Children.Add(Button1);

   Border TooltipBrd = new Border()
   {
       BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
       BorderThickness = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
       HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
       VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
       Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
   };

   TextBlock txtB1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "Lakshman", Margin = new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0) };
   TooltipBrd.Child = txtB1;

   stackPanel5.Children.Add(TooltipBrd);

   System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger1 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
   trigger1.EventName = "MouseEnter";

   ChangePropertyAction action1 = new ChangePropertyAction();
   action1.TargetName = "TooltipBrd";
   action1.PropertyName = "Visibility";
   action1.Value = Visibility.Visible;

   trigger1.Actions.Add(action1);
   trigger1.Attach(Button1);

   System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger2 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
   trigger2.EventName = "MouseLeave";

   ChangePropertyAction action2 = new ChangePropertyAction();
   action2.TargetName = "TooltipBrd";
   action2.PropertyName = "Visibility";
   action2.Value = Visibility.Collapsed;

   trigger2.Actions.Add(action2);
   trigger2.Attach(Button1);
}
```

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, delete all that and use proper DataBinding. There is no need to create UI elements in procedural code in  WPF. Use an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

At the XAML, create the event like this

```
<Button x:Name="sample_btn" MouseEnter="sample_btn_MouseEnter" />
```

now at the code behind,

```
private void logOut_btn_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //your logic on mouse enter
}
```

Similarly, do for mouse leave and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Magnus(MM8) - Given beautiful solution for this.
    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/magnus%20(mm8)/?ws=usercard-mini 

    **Just set the TargetObject property of the actions to TooltipBrd and your code will work:**

           public void LoadData() {
              //VisualState vs = new VisualState();
              //vs.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, YourStateName);

              Button Button1 = new Button() { Cursor = Cursors.Hand, Content = "Press Me!" };
              stackPanel5.Children.Add(Button1);

              Border TooltipBrd = new Border() {
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
              };

              TextBlock txtB1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "Lakshman", Margin = new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0) };
              TooltipBrd.Child = txtB1;

              stackPanel5.Children.Add(TooltipBrd);

              System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger1 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
              trigger1.EventName = "MouseEnter";

              ChangePropertyAction action1 = new ChangePropertyAction();
              action1.**TargetObject** = TooltipBrd;
              action1.PropertyName = "Visibility";
              action1.Value = Visibility.Visible;

              trigger1.Actions.Add(action1);
              trigger1.Attach(Button1);

              System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger2 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
              trigger2.EventName = "MouseLeave";

              ChangePropertyAction action2 = new ChangePropertyAction();
              action2.**TargetObject** = TooltipBrd;
              action2.PropertyName = "Visibility";
              action2.Value = Visibility.Collapsed;

              trigger2.Actions.Add(action2);
              trigger2.Attach(Button1);
            }

    **If you set the TargetName property you need to call the RegisterName method on the StackPanel:**
    int i = 0;
public void LoadData()
        {
            ++i;
            //VisualState vs = new VisualState();
            //vs.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, YourStateName);

            Button Button1 = new Button() { Cursor = Cursors.Hand, Content = "Press Me!", Height = 150, Width=150 };
            stackPanel5.Children.Add(Button1);

            Border TooltipBrd = new Border()
            {
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            };

            TextBlock txtB1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "Lakshman", Margin = new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0) };
            TooltipBrd.Child = txtB1;

            stackPanel5.Children.Add(TooltipBrd);

            System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger1 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
            trigger1.EventName = "MouseEnter";

            ChangePropertyAction action1 = new ChangePropertyAction();
            //action1.TargetObject = TooltipBrd;
            action1.TargetName = "TooltipBrd"+i;
            action1.PropertyName = "Visibility";
            action1.Value = Visibility.Visible;

            trigger1.Actions.Add(action1);
            trigger1.Attach(Button1);

            System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger2 = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
            trigger2.EventName = "MouseLeave";

            ChangePropertyAction action2 = new ChangePropertyAction();
            action2.TargetName = "TooltipBrd"+i;
            //action2.TargetObject = TooltipBrd;
            action2.PropertyName = "Visibility";
            action2.Value = Visibility.Collapsed;

            trigger2.Actions.Add(action2);
            trigger2.Attach(Button1);
            **stackPanel5.RegisterName("TooltipBrd"+i, TooltipBrd);**
        }    
    When you are creating controls dynamically, you have to call the RegisterName method for the runtime or you to be able to find them using this name.
```

Comment: This goes against all well-known, accepted good  practices and patterns in WPF. -1.